# Error a generar lista de datos linq

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

Me Lanza el siguiente error:

> The entity or complex type 'SisVentaOnlinne.Models.Card' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Este es el metodo que me genera la lista con los datos:

```
    public List<Card> GetCard()
    {
        var user = db.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var card = (from Cards in db.Cards.Where(u => u.Id_Usuario == user.Id_Usuario)
                    select new Card
                    {
                        CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber.Replace((Cards.CardNumber.Substring(1 - 1, 12)), "************"),
                        IdCard = Cards.IdCard,
                    }).ToList();

        return card.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930096/the-entity-or-complex-type-ws-models-xxxx-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que intentas construir un modelo a partir de una entidad y lo peor podría venir cuando dejas abierta la transacción hacia el View porque envías un `db.Cars`.

Lo ideal es usar un modelo para que tengas la interacción con la vista y además hacer un `dispose` de la transacción.

Clase del modelo (Data Transfer Object):

```
public class CardsModel
{
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string IdCard { get; set; }
}
```

Código del Controlador:

```
public List<Card> GetCard()
{
    List<CardsModel> cards = new List<CardsModel>();

    using(db = new DataContext()){
        var user = db.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        cards = (from Cards in db.Cards
                where Cards.Id_Usuario == user.Id_Usuario
                select new CardsModel
                {
                    CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber.Replace((Cards.CardNumber.Substring(1 - 1, 12)), "************"),
                    IdCard = Cards.IdCard,
                }).ToList();
    }
    return card.ToList();
}
```

Comment: me lanza el siguiente error Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NotSupportedException' en EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: The entity or complex type 'SisVentaOnlinne.Models.Card' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera Bien, cambié la sentencia `where` como parte de la consulta Linq, prueba y me cuentas ;)

Comment: No entiendo, lo que hice fue comentar la variable user y no me funciono

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera si logras ver no comenté nada de código, revisa la actualización que realicé e hice el cambio de la condición a la consulta Linq.

Comment: Me sale el mismo error,

Comment: El problema no es el usuario porque en el debug lo esta encontrando es cuando intenta buscar la lista de cards, que da el problema